# How to monitor for Active Directory App Registration secret expiration?

Tags: azure-active-directory, monitoring

We have app registrations created in Active Directory and we have secrets created for those apps. Secrets have expiration dates and we are looking for the best way to anticipate the expiration for the secrets.
We want to know if we can monitor secret expiration in advance and then create new secrets to be sure we will not have outages for applications using the secrets.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot monitor the Expiration Date for App Registration in the Azure Portal.

Instead, we can use a powershell script to send mail alert for the App Registration secret expirations.

For example, if the expiration date of App Registration client secret is less than one week of the current date, we can send a mail using SMTP server.

As per the Microsoft Docs, You must specify a Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) server or the Send-MailMessage command fails. Use the SmtpServer parameter or set the $PSEmailServer variable to a valid SMTP server. The value assigned to $PSEmailServer is the default SMTP setting for PowerShell

```
$expirationDate = (Get-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId App-Registration-ObjectID).EndDate
$currentDate = Get-Date
if ($currentDate -gt $expirationDate.AddDays(-7)) 
{
    Send-MailMessage -From 'Source-MailID' -To Destination-Mail-ID' -Subject 'Test mail'
}
```

Reference : [Send-MailMessage (Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility) - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=Send-Mail%20Message%201%20Description.%20The%20Send-MailMessage%20cmdlet%20sends,pipe%20the%20paths%20and%20file%20names%20to%20Send-MailMessage.)